# Rogue resistance between Vout and GND in LDO circuit

Tags: pcb-design, resistance, ldo, troubleshooting, transceiver

I'm currently developing a circuit as seen [here:](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481647/voltage-regulator-overheating).

[image: Transceiver circuit with 24 VDC]

I had some suggestions to check my Iout to ensure that I wasn't drawing so much current that I was causing an overheat. After a little checking I believe that my circuit is way under the threshold (~22 mA.)

I've managed to solder up PCBs that **have worked**, but the vast majority don't. Today when double checking for any strange shorts, I noticed a rogue resistance between Vout on the LDO and GND (~60-100 Ω.) That resistance doesn't exist on the PCBs that do work.

*Note: I've tested this circuit with a couple different LDOs and had the same results on each.*

Is there a way for me to further troubleshoot this issue? (I don't really know where to start looking for component failure etc.)

Or perhaps any suggestions as to what's causing this strange behaviour?

Is there perhaps an occurrence where the first connection of the circuit is causing something to break?

Comment: Hi I was wondering what are the values of C3 and C4?  Could you post a photo or layout of the PCB?

Comment: Just a comment, you may want to read this link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/41856

Comment: What kind of flux are you using when you assemble these boards? Does it get properly cleaned afterwards? Flux can cause significant changes in conductivity in certain areas of the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, disconnect power to the circuit, then short the IN and OUT pins of the regulator to ground.

Now, check your resistance from OUT to GROUND and see if it still gives you a low resistance.

If you still find that 100 ohms, then start removing components from your PCB.

1. Remove one component that connects to OUT from the regulator.
2. Check the resistance.
3. If the resistance is still low, go to step 1.
4. Repeat until all components are gone or until the resistance changes drastically.
5. The regulator itself is, of course, one of the components you'll remove.

If you remove all components and still have low resistance between OUT and GROUND, then the PCB is bad or you've accidentally made a short circuit on it somewhere.

---

If you determine that it has to be the PCB, then you can destructively find the bad spot.

1. Get a high voltage (50V or so) power supply that can deliver a couple of amperes.
2. Connect the power supply to the OUT and GROUND pin pads for the regulator.
3. If there's a short on the board somewhere, it will either pop and blow out or get hot enough for you to locate it.

Wear safety goggles and keep your hands clear of the board while doing this "test."

---

Now that you've found the culprit, and determined that it dies at poweron, you can start looking for the real cause.

After a quick run through the [datasheet,](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3221E-MAX3243E.pdf) the only thing I can find is that it might be the capacitors in the charge pump.

This chart from the datasheet  shows the recommended minimum values for the charge pump capacitors given the supply voltage:

[image]

Given that you said that you are converting the circuit to run on 3.3V and that it was designed to run on 5V, maybe the capacitors need to be swapped out.

The datasheet doesn't spell out what will happen if the capacitors are too small.  It may be that the charge pump just has to much ripple on the output - but maybe it causes too much load on some switching transistor if it tries to get 5V from 3.3V with too small capacitors.

In any case, the datasheet makes a point of ensuring that you have at least the minimum and that you should allow for aging and temperature effects.

That's all I can come up with.  Maybe that's it, or maybe it's something else entirely.

Comment: Brill! Thanks for the advice, I'll have a go and see what I can find out :)

Comment: I've had a short in a complex 8 layer board some 20 years ago that I could not find by conventional means. Some 10 awg wires and a 12V car battery located the short in seconds. Turned out to be a misplaced via that shorted a digital ground to an analogue ground.

Comment: @MichaelKaras did you drill out the remaining boards' vias or get new ones made?

Comment: Yeah, Just drilled them out. Probably built 8 or 9 prototype units like that and then spun the artwork for next build release.

Comment: @JRE it looks to be the MAX3221. Interestingly the resistance between OUT and GND all looks ok when soldering up(E.g. Out of scope or occasionally ~200k), but the moment I plug it in is when the MAX IC fries.

I should note that previous to this version, I had a circuit that ran nicely with a 5 V REG, but I swapped it out so I could forward 3.3V to the other side of this circuit (via the RJ45). I'm wondering If I'm just missing something fundamental with the capacitors attached to the regulator? I've tried a couple different regulators (L78L33ABZ-AP & BA033CC0) but had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is either that:

1. You have damaged (perhaps by ESD) MAX3221 chips that are creating a short across the power rails.
2. You have a bad batch of PCBs (it's been a very long time since I've seen hair shorts on PCBs, but I have seen them from a Taiwan maker many years ago and they were in the 10-100\$\Omega\$ range. If you've purchased claimed 100% tested PCBs from a reliable supplier this should not be true, especially in any number, but it's still possible.

There are other possibilities such as shorted ceramic caps with less probability.

If the MAX3221 is getting hot with a 'stiff' supply, that will be the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. 
Yes It looks like its the MAX3221 that's shorting out. The resistance looks ok up until I add power to the circuit and then it seems to fry. I can't claim I have the most amazing ESD protection setup, so perhaps it's just something really stupid i'm doing when making the circuits up.
I've used JLC for the PCBs who claim to do flying probe checks, so fingers crossed it's not that.

Comment: I'd be a little careful, especially if the MAX3221 might be clones. ESD protection is a bit of a black art, AFAIUI.